# Advanced css menu pop up on the right

Tags: css, css-float, css-transitions, css-transforms

Down below the picture is my code for my css menu where it says 
**Sub Item** i want that area to popup on the left of where it says **Product1**
thank you soo much in advance.. i used CSS menu makers to make this but they dont have an option to chose where it floats

im posting my code below the image

[image]

```
/** Body Of Website */

   body{
      background-image:url('/images/background.png');
      background-color:#0a1857;
     }

/** Advanced css menu */


#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu {height: 70px; background-color: rgb(35,35,35); box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px  rgba(0,0,0,.4);}


#cssmenu > ul > li {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 35px;
   position: relative;
  }

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
   color: rgb(160,160,160);
   font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
   font-size: 15px;
   line-height: 70px;
   padding: 15px 20px;
 -webkit-transition: color .15s;
  -moz-transition: color .15s;
    -o-transition: color .15s;
       transition: color .15s;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {color: rgb(250,250,250); }


#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
   background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
   text-align: left;
   position: absolute;
   top: 55px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -90px;
   width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
       transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
       border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
       box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 }

 #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
   opacity: 1;
   top: 65px;
   visibility: visible;
}

 #cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before{
   content: '';
   display: block;
   border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -20px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -10px;
 }

 #cssmenu > ul ul > li { position: relative;}

 #cssmenu ul ul a{
   color: rgb(50,50,50);
   font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
   font-size: 13px;
   background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
   padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
   display: block;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
    -o-transition: background-color .1s;
       transition: background-color .1s;
 }

 #cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background-color: rgb(240,240,240);}


 #cssmenu ul ul ul {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: -16px;
   left: 206px;
   padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
   background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
   text-align: left;
   width: 160px;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
       transition: all .3s;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
       box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 }


 #cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}


 #cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
   background-color: rgb(205,44,36);
   color: rgb(240,240,240);
 }
```

Comment: Can you also post a jsfiddle? Also note that you don't have much space on your left side so it won't pop up there on your screen without absolute positioning which might break the layout on other resolutions.

Comment: @Mr.Flocker as you requested http://jsfiddle.net/RAu76/

Comment: have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this apply the following style or change the value for "left" if you want

```
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {

left: -50px; **Change this to whatever you want to**
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

^ this is on line number **105** of your CSS stylesheet.

Hope this helps! Let me know how it goes :)

UPDATE:-

Change this as well

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
left: -50px; /* Change this to whatever value you used for the above "left" attribute */
```

This should fix the strange transition issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RAu76/4/ ok i got it fixed but then u go to the text it kinda moves away from you if u help me fix this ill tick ur answer

Comment: Good to know it worked! And you mean that the text is basically unreachable and not clickable right? If so, then let me update my answer accordingly.

Comment: go to my link and slowly move the mouse to the sub menu it kinda moves away

Comment: Oh OK, I get it now. That's because when you try to move your mouse to that subMenu, due to the small space for preview in jsfiddle, "Contact" gets in the way and you hover over it then instead of subMenu but this should work fine in your normal page/browser. Although it it's still not something you wanted, let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: does the same thing if you move the mouse to slow its like not even a second

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31081/discussion-between-jacob-anthony-tonna-and-mr-flocker)

Comment: i posted my website link in chat

Answer (score 1):

Cant you manually position the sub menu?

Just add a class to the sub menu, and

`subnav { position: absolute; top:10;left:10; }`?